# Azure Mobile Service Single Sign on Microsoft Account

Tags: azure-mobile-services, azure-connect

I have implemented single sign on using the WL api, but I only recently realized that I need to call mobileService.login on top of that to use the nice authentication features of Azure Mobile Services.

I followed this tutorial

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/single-sign-on-windows-8-js/#add-authentication

and added this piece of code:

```
var login = function () {
    return new WinJS.Promise(function (complete) {
        WL.init();

        WL.login({ scope: ["wl.signin", "wl.basic", "wl.birthday", "wl.emails"] }).then(function (result) {
            session = result.session;


            WinJS.Promise.join([
                WL.api({ path: "me", method: "GET" }),
                mobileService.login("microsoftaccount", session.authentication_token)
            ]).done(function (results) {
                var profile = results[0];
                var mobileServicesUser = results[1];

                var title = "Welcome " + profile.first_name + "!";
                var message = "You are now logged in as: " + mobileServicesUser.userId;
                var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(message, title);
                dialog.showAsync().done(complete);
            });
        }, function (error) {
            session = null;
            var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("You must log in.", "Login Required");
            dialog.showAsync().done(complete);
        });
    });
}
```

however on this line

```
mobileService.login("microsoftaccount", session.authentication_token)
```

my session.authentication_token is undefined. (I have an access_token)

If I don't pass the token, I am prompted to sign in every time I launch the app, which defeats the purpose of the integrated sign on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the authentication token, you need to pass the redirect URI to the call to `WL.init`:

```
WL.init({
    redirect_uri: "<< INSERT REDIRECT DOMAIN HERE >>"
});
```

Where the redirect domain must be the same as the one in your Live Connect application.

Comment: Thank you! I also had to change my login call to say mobileService.login("microsoftaccount", { "authenticationToken": session.authentication_token })